# Android Twitter sendDirectMessages not working

Tags: android, twitter4j

I am trying to send the Direct messages from my Android app. For that I have Googled and found the following solution from the links . In that Twitter4j I have found the code snippet. I have tried the same in my Android app also, but got the issue:

**http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html**

```
// The factory instance is re-useable and thread safe.
    Twitter sender = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
    DirectMessage message = sender.sendDirectMessage(recipientId, message);
    System.out.println("Sent: " message.getText() + " to @" + message.getRecipientScreenName());


Issue :
**10-10 20:04:26.440: E/AndroidRuntime(6935): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Authentication credentials are missing. See http://twitter4j.org/configuration.html for the detail.**
```

Please help me to come out of this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says:

> Authentication credentials are missing.

From the Twitter4J [Code Examples](http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html) page:

> To run the example codes, you need to have OAuth credentials configured in twitter4j.properties. See [Twitter4J - Configuration](http://twitter4j.org/en/configuration.html) for the detail.

You can't send direct messages on Twitter unless you're logged in (unlike some other features, like reading a random user's status updates).  You'll need to configure your authentication credentials by one of the three methods given on the Twitter4J Configuration page before the code example will work.

Comment: i have got the following Exception while trying to send the direct message to my followers . 10-11 11:21:45.930: W/System.err(11946): 403:The request is understood, but it has been refused. An accompanying error message will explain why. This code is used when requests are being denied due to update limits (https://support.twitter.com/articles/15364-about-twitter-limits-update-api-dm-and-following).
10-11 11:21:45.930: W/System.err(11946): error - You cannot send messages to users who are not following you.